# How can i set the Form to be in the Center of the Screen?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    //this.Location = new Point(form1_location_on_x, form1_location_on_y);
    //this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Either the line

```
this.Location = new Point(form1_location_on_x, form1_location_on_y);
```

or the line

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

are working when I'm on my original screen resolution 1920x1080, but once I'm changing the resolution to 1024x768, the Form is on the right bottom corner not hidden I see it all but it's not in the center.

form1_location_on_x and on_y are:

```
form1_location_on_x = this.Location.X;
form1_location_on_y = this.Location.Y;
```

The question is what should I do to make it work on any other resolution like 1024x768 or any others? I tried many changes but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Are you changing the resolution while the application is running?

Comment: Tested it while it's running. If i first exit the application change resolution and running the application again it's ok. But if the user will change the resolution while the application is running ?

Comment: Clearly you'll need to set WindowState *before* calling Show().  The odds that the window hasn't been created yet by the time this event runs are not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the top and left position of your form using this formula:

```
int formWidth = yourForm.Width;
int formHeight = yourForm.Height;
int screenH = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top + 
              Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height) / 2;
int screenW = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left + 
              Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width) / 2;

int top = screenH - formWidth / 2;
int left = screenW - formHeight / 2;
yourForm.Location = new Point(top, left);
```

Of course, these days, you have the problem of dual monitors.
I don't know if you want your form to appear always on the primary screen or you want the form appear in the current screen (the one where the form is currently displayed). In this second case you need to find where your form is displayed

```
private void CenterForm(Form yuorForm)
{    
    foreach(var s in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
       if(s.WorkingArea.Contains(yourForm.Location))
       {
            int screenH = s.WorkingArea.Height / 2;
            int screenW = s.WorkingArea.Width / 2;

            int top = (screenH + s.WorkingArea.Top) - formWidth / 2;
            int left = (screenW + s.WorkingArea.Left) - formHeight / 2;
            yourForm.Location = new Point(top, left);
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @alex I will complete the answer with the information on [SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class

If you want to be notified by the system when the user suddenly change the resolution of your screen you could subscribe to the event `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` (`using Microsoft.Win32;` needed)

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
```

and then handle the reposition of your form in the event

```
// This method is called when the display settings change.
void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RecenterForm(yourForm);
}
```

Comment: Steve your solution is working when the application is running i minimize it then double click to resize it back. But when the application is running and the Form is in the center of screen after running it first time then i change the resolution so the Form is no on right bottom corner i need to minimize it then resize it. I wonder if there is any event that can detect screen resoltuion changes ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 4):

```
Size screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
Location = new Point(screenSize.Width / 2 - Width / 2, screenSize.Height / 2 - Height / 2);
```

Make sure that you set   `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`

Tested and working with 1920x1080 and 1024 x 768

Comment: Where are you getting the Width and Height variables from - from the primary form?

Answer (score 1):

try using one of these after the resize:

```
this.CenterToScreen();
```

or

```
this.CenterToParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StartPosition` *property* of `Form` objects. It determines the **position** of a form. Set it's value to `CenterScreen` if you want your form to open in the center of the screen

Comment: Representing sample code, or screen shot supports the answer and makes it much more clear

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate function for this, which you could name CenterToScreen or what have you, since C# that I am using lacks the CenterToParent and CenterToScreen functions. I pass the Form this to it, and inside that function, I can do a Screen.FromControl(formname).WorkingArea.Size and do all the calculations. Screen.PrimaryScreen can be null but using the passed in form and then calling the Screen.FromControl() method on it does not raise a nullable warning.

e.g.:

```
public static void CenterOnScreen(Control c)
{
    Screen s = Screen.FromControl(c);
    Size size = s.WorkingArea.Size;
    int x =  size.Width / 2 - c.Width / 2;
    int y = size.Height / 2 - c.Height / 2;
    c.Location = new(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks! The easiest way to post code is to paste it, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the code block button. That will indent the selected text by 4 spaces, which causes it to get rendered as code. The other option is to _not_ indent it, but instead fence it by prefixing it with `\`\`\`` on a line by itself, and the same thing after the code block on another line by itself. See [code block] for more detail.